# @Ionic/Angular peer dependency on rxjs conflicts with @ionic-native/core

Tags: npm, ionic-framework, rxjs, ionic-native

I have a dependency issue in my [@ionic/angular 7.1.1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ionic/angular/v/7.1.1?activeTab=readme) project.

[@ionic-native/core latest ver 5.36](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ionic-native/core/v/5.36.0?activeTab=readme) appears to have a peer dependency on an rxjs [version compatible with](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22345808/14956277) 5.5.0 or 6.5.0.

[image: A screenshot of the NPM page for the ionic native core package's dependency file showing a peer dependency on rxjs compatible with version 5.5 or 6.5]

I can't install this rxjs version because @ionic/angular 7.1.1 requires rxjs >= 7.5.0.

[image: A screenshot of the NPM page for the ionic angular package's dependency file showing a peer dependency on rxjs greater than or equal to version 7.5.0]

So how do I get around this?

Project Info:

```
Ionic CLI                     : 7.0.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 7.1.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 16.1.3
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 16.1.3
@angular/cli                  : 16.1.3
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 9.0.0
```

Capacitor:

```
Capacitor CLI      : 5.1.0
@capacitor/android : not installed
@capacitor/core    : 5.1.0
@capacitor/ios     : not installed
```

Utility:

```
cordova-res (update available: 0.15.4) : 0.15.2
native-run (update available: 1.7.3)   : 1.7.2
```

System:

```
NodeJS : v18.14.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
npm    : 9.3.1
OS     : macOS Catalina
```

Error:

```
npm i @ionic-native/native-page-transitions
   
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: LabCPD@0.0.1
npm ERR! Found: rxjs@7.8.1
npm ERR! node_modules/rxjs
npm ERR!   rxjs@"^7.8.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer rxjs@"^5.5.0 || ^6.5.0" from @ionic-native/core@5.36.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@ionic-native/core
npm ERR!   @ionic-native/core@"^5.36.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution
```

I tried adding backward compatibility for modules with dependencies of rxjs versions up to 6.6.7, in my package.json:

```
"rxjs": "^7.8.1",
"rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
```

Then I deleted my node_modules folder, package-lock.json file, and ran `npm install` but I still had issues.

@ionic-native/core and [@ionic-native/native-page-transitions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ionic-native/native-page-transitions/v/5.36.0) are both latest versions 5.36 and they require rxjs 5.5.0 or 6.5.0, so not sure why rxjs-compact 6.6.7 doesn't provide backward compatibility needed.

Comment: I made a couple edits to make clear that you're dealing with `@ionic/angular` version 7.1.1. which is *much* different from dealing with `@angular/core` version 7.1.1 (which is nearly half a decade old).

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but good luck!

Comment: Thanks, there seems to be a move a way from ionic-native for Cordova plug-ins in capacitor apps and using @awesome-corodva-plugins instead, the answer might in there -I’ll take a look for the latter equivalents of ionic-native page transition plugins , see https://ionic.io/blog/a-new-chapter-for-ionic-native

Comment: Docs for anyone  else with similar issues : https://github.com/danielsogl/awesome-cordova-plugins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of ~ September 27, 2021 all Cordova plugins were moved to a community maintainer.
You will need to move all @ionic-native/* packages to their new package name: @awesome-cordova-plugins/*.

```
npm install cordova-plugin-name
npm install @awesome-cordova-plugins/name
```

Awesome Cordova plugin [list](https://github.com/danielsogl/awesome-cordova-plugins/tree/master/docs/plugins)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue during upgrading Ionic and Angular, I removed all @ionic-native packages and installed @awesome-cordova-plugins
you can find all plugins here
https://github.com/danielsogl/awesome-cordova-plugins/tree/master/docs/plugins

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35559938)